# OpenAL alGenBuffers Error Code 40964 Solution

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I am a noob for openAL programming, there is an error which I encountered.

My code is following:

```
ALuint test_buffer[10];
ALenum error;
alGenBuffers(10,test_buffer);
if((error=alGetError())!=AL_NO_ERROR){
  std::cout<<"alGenBuffer Error:"<<error<<std::endl;
}
```

Then I get error code 40964. 
How to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to look-up the result in the openAL constants, then print a more meaningful error. Something along the lines of:

```
public static String openAlErrorToString(int err) {
switch (err) {
  case AL_NO_ERROR: return "AL_NO_ERROR";
  case AL_INVALID_DEVICE: return "AL_INVALID_DEVICE";
  case AL_INVALID_CONTEXT: return "AL_INVALID_CONTEXT";
  case AL_INVALID_ENUM: return "AL_INVALID_ENUM";
  case AL_INVALID_VALUE: return "AL_INVALID_VALUE";
  case AL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: return "AL_OUT_OF_MEMORY";
  /* ... */
  default:
    return "Unknown error code";
}
```

A quick google reveals that 40964 could be `AL_INVALID_OPERATION` or `AL_INVALID_VALUE`.

From [the docs](https://www.openal.org/documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf) for `alGenBuffers`, this only pushes:

- `AL_INVALID_VALUE` if the buffer array isn't large enough to hold the
  number of buffers requested.
- `AL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` if there is not enough memory available to
  generate all the buffers requested.

So your `AL_INVALID_OPERATION` could be an error from earlier in your program. Perhaps you have a left-over error code on stack? Call `alGetError()` before your buffer initialisation to rule that out.